# Equivalent BAPI for a MB01 transaction?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm trying to replace some un-reliable sap scripting we have in place to do an MB01 from a custom goods receipt application. I have come across the .NET connector and it looks like it could do a job for me.

Research has churned up the BAPI called BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE but can anyone tell me what parameters might be required to perform this transaction?

I have access to a SAP test environment.

BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE accepts a table of values called GOODSMVT_ITEM which contains 121 fields. I'm sure that not all of these fields are required.

Ultimately I guess my question is, what how can I work out which ones are required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to a SAP system?  I have recently used this BAPI, and it has quite detailed documentation.  To view the documentation, use transaction SE37, and enter the BAPI name.  Unfortunately I don't currently have access to a system.

You will have to ask one of your MM/Logistics people to tell you what the movement type (BWART) is, and depending on the config you will need details like material number (MATNR), plant (WERKS), storage location etc.

Comment: I do have access to a test SAP environment, I guess my question is the BAPI takes a table called GOODSMVT_ITEM which contains a 121 fields. I am certain that some of these fields are required to do the call. How can I work out which are required without crazy trial and error?

Comment: From what I remember the BADI documentation detailed exactly which fields were required depending on which movement type you are working with.  You are right, only a handful of fields are mandatory. Sorry that I can't be of more help at this stage.

Comment: I found more documentation which lists the required fields depending on my movement code. SE37 is the structure and field listing but to get to anything useful, there is a button labeled function module documentation in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

MB01 is a *Post GR for PO transaction*, it is an equivalent of GM_Code **01** in `MIGO` or `BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE`. `MIGO` transaction is a modern successor for obsolete MB01.

So, as per the `BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE` documentation for GM_Code 01 the following fields are mandatory:

- Purchase order
- Purchase order item
- Movement type
- Movement indicator
- Quantity in unit of entry
- ISO code unit of measurement for unit of entry or
  quantity proposal

Here is the sample:

```
gmhead-pstng_date = sy-datum.
gmhead-doc_date = sy-datum.
gmhead-pr_uname = sy-uname.
gmcode-gm_code = '01'.

loop at pcitab.
  itab-move_type  = pcitab-mvt_type.
  itab-mvt_ind    = 'B'.
  itab-plant      = pcitab-plant.
  itab-material   = pcitab-material.
  itab-entry_qnt  = pcitab-qty.
  itab-move_stloc = pcitab-recv_loc.
  itab-stge_loc   = pcitab-issue_loc.
  itab-po_number  = pcitab-pur_doc.
  itab-po_item    = pcitab-po_item.
  concatenate pcitab-del_no pcitab-del_item into itab-item_text.
  itab-move_reas  = pcitab-scrap_reason.
  append itab.
endloop.

call function 'BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE'
  exporting
    goodsmvt_header  = gmhead
    goodsmvt_code    = gmcode
 IMPORTING
    goodsmvt_headret = mthead
  tables
    goodsmvt_item    = itab
    return           = errmsg
```